# Introduction to the Newman-Penrose Formalism

Tags: general-relativity, resource-recommendations

I am having trouble finding good introductory literature (e.g. a textbook or lecture notes) for the Newman-Penrose formalism of General Relativity.

I am looking for a resource suitable for someone who has read, say, all of Carroll's book and the first part of Wald's book, and who has skimmed a few of the advanced topics in the second half of Wald (e.g. I am familiar with congruences and optical scalars, singularities, causal structure, compactification, and black holes).

Comment: The original articles are remarkably clear IMHO. Why don't you give them a look and report back?

Comment: see e.g. [Spin-coefficient formalism](http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Spin-coefficient_formalism) and references therein,

Comment: See the second chapter in the book of Zafar Ahsan, The Potential of Fields in Einstein's Theory of Gravitation https://link-springer-com.www.sndl1.arn.dz/chapter/10.1007/978-981-13-8976-4_2 The original paper: Newman, E.T., Penrose, An Approach to gravitational radiation by a method of spin coefficients, J. Math. Phys. 3, 566--578 (1962)